# Regex getting String in between parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am just learning about using Regex and it does seem a bit complicated to me.

I am trying to parse this String in Java:

```
new Array(new Array('1','Hello'),new Array('2','World (New) Again'),new Array('3','Now'));
```

I want the output to end up as these matches:

```
'1','Hello'
'2','World (New) Again'
'3','Now'
```

I tried a few pattern, but the best I can get is that I get:

```
'1','Hello'
'2','World (New
) Again'
'3','Now'
```

This is my code:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("([^\\(]*[']*['][^\\)]*[']*)");
s = "new Array(new Array('1','Hello'),new Array('2','World (New) Again'),new Array('3','Now'));";
Matcher matcher = pattern2.matcher(s);

while(matcher.find()){
    String match = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(match); 
}
```

Comment: For syntax parsing, regex is not the best tool. It's likely to be feasible in your case, but very fragile. You should implement your own parser.

Comment: "I tried a few pattern," WHat did you try? And you're trying to count balanced parentheses which regexps are not suited to. As @Mena says, parse the strings some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work if the json string format is like the above.

```
String s = "new Array(new Array('1','Hello'),new Array('2','World (New) Again'),new Array('3','Now'));";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[(,]new\\sArray\\(((?:(?!\\),new\\sArray|\\)+;).)*)\\)");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
 }
```

**Output:**

```
'1','Hello'
'2','World (New) Again'
'3','Now'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yX6lH6/4)

Comment: Avinash, this work. Thanks. I am also aware that this may not work if there is multiple space in between the commas?

Comment: then add `\s*` where the spaces are located. If you Still can't figure it out, then provide a sample string. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split making sure there are no close brackets between the close/open pairs:

You can do the whole thing in one line:

```
String[] parts = str.replaceAll("^(new Array\\()*|\\)*;$", "").split("\\)[^)]*?Array\\(");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "new Array(new Array('1','Hello'),new Array('2','World (New) Again'),new Array('3','Now'));";
String[] parts = str.replaceAll("^(new Array\\()*|\\)*;$", "").split("\\)[^)]*?Array\\(");
for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

Output:

```
'1','Hello'
'2','World (New) Again'
'3','Now'
```

Comment: However, I cannot strip the open/close brackets in the quote.